# How to represent the word "something"?

Tags: translation

How would you translate "I will buy something"?
I came up with:
なにかかいます。

But I'm not sure if this is correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In common speech many people say things like:

> スーパーで何{なに}か買{か}ってきます。

You can also say「なんか」 instead of 「なにか」 to mean "something" in this case if you like.

Comment: スーパー**で**何か買いに行きます。 sounds (sounded) a little bit strange to me. This is probably because when we use 「(verb)+に行く」, like 「買いに行く」, the particle marking location words corresponds to the 「行く」 part of the verb phrase, not the preceding verb. So スーパー**に/へ**何か買いに**行きます**。 (as you would say スーパーへ/に行きます。) ,  rather than *スーパー**で何か買いに**行きます。 (as you would say スーパーで何か買います。) , is what people are more likely to say.